# Internal Server Error 500 in laravel

Tags: php, .htaccess, laravel-4, laravel-routing

I deployed my project on aws server and its run successfully but when i again try to deploy it on different server it returns internal server error 500

[image]

.htaccess code below

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On

# Redirect Trailing Slashes...
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

So why my site is not running

Thanks in advance

Comment: Error 500 means: look into the `error.log`.

Comment: nothing on error.log file.im confused

Comment: look into the apache "error_log". In unix systems probably under /var/log/apache(2)/error_log. Print that in your question. If by any weird reason nothing is in the file. Print the app/storage/logs/laravel.log file.

Comment: Click on the link provided in the console and let me know the response that you get...